# Получить доступ к методу из другого класса (Java)

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно обратиться из цикла while к методу `public static void checkScore(Student s)` для проверки условий (т.е, если бы не было класса, а только метод `checkScore`, я бы мог использовать `checkScore(student1);`, а как сделать то же самое, но имея класс `class StudentOffice`?)

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Student student1 = new Student("Nikita", 2, true, 3000);

        while (true){
            System.out.println("Если вы хотите пойти на лекцию, введите 1, иначе, введите 0");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (student1.status == true){
                if (number == 1){
                    goToLecture(student1);
                }
                else
                    goToBuffet(student1);
            }
            else if (student1.status == false){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Извините, но вы были отчислены из университета, до свидания");
    }
    public static class StudentOffice{
        public static void checkScore(Student s) {
            if (s.score < 0){
                s.status = false;
        }
            if (s.score >= 4){
              s.stip = 3100;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Видимо, так: StudentOffice.checkScore(student1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите в цикле: `StudentOffice.checkScore(student1);`